# How to keep divs position fixed even after deleting its neighbors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple script that creates and deletes divs when pushing buttons.

```
$("#add").click(function(){
    $(document.body).append('<div class="bloc">'+(++_INDEX)+'</div>');
});

$("#del").click(function(){
    $(".bloc:first").remove();
});
```

My issue is with the "Delete" part, I need all the divs to stay at their current position when deleting anything.

And once I recreate new ones, they should take up the blank space left from previously deleted ones.

Could this be done through HTML/CSS only ? If not, how can I solve this ?

Please see the code example here: https://jsfiddle.net/t6wvLyjb/

Comment: instead of deleting them just hide them. Hide as in change visibility

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla  but when creating new ones, that would leave some blank areas.

Comment: for creating you can first make all the hidden ones visible and after everything is made visible, create new divs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to do that because once a div has been removed from the dom rest of the elements will rearrange. One way to do is create elements absolutely(which is also difficult) and store their locations. While deleting you will not have a problem but while adding you have to add them to the previously stored locations.

Another option is to change the visibility of blocks instead of removing them. When adding instead of creating new ones first make all the blocks visible first and then create new ones.

You can do something like this

```
var _INDEX = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#add").click(function(){
        if(!$('.bloc.removed').length){
            $(document.body).append('<div class="bloc">'+(++_INDEX)+'</div>');
        }else{
            $(".bloc.removed").first().removeClass('removed');
        }
    });

    $("#del").click(function(){
        $(".bloc:not(.removed)").first().addClass('removed');
    });

});
```

```js
var _INDEX = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#add").click(function() {
    if (!$('.bloc.removed').length) {
      $(document.body).append('<div class="bloc">' + (++_INDEX) + '</div>');
    } else {
      $(".bloc.removed").first().removeClass('removed');
    }
  });

  $("#del").click(function() {
    $(".bloc:not(.removed)").first().addClass('removed');
  });

});
```

```css
.bloc {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 64px;
}
.removed {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Add" id="add" />
<input type="button" value="Del" id="del" />
<br/>
```

Here is a demo **https://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/t6wvLyjb/1/**

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS making the position fixed or absolute. This way you will have the position of the element fixed to place.

I don't know if it will work when you delete elements but worth a shot.